# How to avoid contention on ConcurrentBag<T>.GetEnumerator()

Tags: .net, concurrency

I am trying to solve a perf issue dealing with Contention on a very highly used Log Writer class. What I see is Contention caused by ConcurrentBag.GetEnumerator() method when we iterate over the bag items from multiple threads. Looking at the code for GetEnumerator(), I see the method calls FreezeBag() which in turn calls AquireAllLocks(), which is root of the contentions. I am looking for help designing a way to avoid this.

Below is abbreviated class design. The class registers any number of logging 'IPlugin' objects, which we add to the ConcurrentBag instance. The WriteLog() method is called at high scale, by many threads. The WriteLog() methods must iterate thru the list of plugins to call IPlugin.WriteLog() on each item.

```
public static class Monitor
{
    internal static ConcurrentBag<IPlugin> Plugins = new ConcurrentBag<IPlugin>();

    public static void WriteLog(int code, params object[] arguments)
    {
        foreach (IPlugin plugin in Plugins)
        {
            plugin.WriteLog(code, arguments);
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterForEvents(IPlugin plugin)
    {
        if (plugin == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plugin");
        }

        Plugins.Add(plugin);
    }
}
```

My first thought is to replace the ConcurrentBag with a List. I can lock around the List.Add() method to make that thread safe, but then I need to lock inside WriteLog() around the iterator because we cannot change the collection while using the iterator. I can have locking/contention during the Register call because we only register a few IPlugins. I cannot afford any contention in the WriteLog() method.

Anyone help me with pattern to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found answer using Immutable Collection. Info and examples here: [System.Collections.Immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections)

Basically, the items in the collection are immutable so no need to lock on the GetEnumerator() call. When we need to add a new plugin to collection, the ImmutableList is copied to a new ImmutableList and assigned to the shared static variabale. If a thread has already gotten an Enumeration with GetEnumerator() prior, then it will have the 'old list'. This way the high-scale WriteEvent never blocks.

```
public static class Monitor
{
    internal static ImmutableList<IPlugin> Plugins = ImmutableList.Create<IPlugin>();

    public static void WriteLog(int code, params object[] arguments)
    {
        foreach (IPlugin plugin in Plugins)
        {
            plugin.WriteLog(code, arguments);
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterForEvents(IPlugin plugin)
    {
        if (plugin == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plugin");
        }

        Plugins = Plugins.Add(plugin);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Plugins = Plugins.Add(plugin)` line has a race condition. If two plugins are registered concurrently, one may be dropped. You can use `ImmutableInterlocked` to ensure no items are lost.